# how linux's alarm() is handled by kernel

Tags: linux, timer, linux-kernel, system-calls, alarm

I was reading about how the **alarm()** call works on the linux. 
**alarm(5)** would send a **SIGALRM** in a minimum of 5 seconds to the process which has made this call. 
The alarm is caused at that moment thanks to a down counter which is set by the kernel reaching zero. 
My doubt is here - we can have N number of processes which make an alarm call, and there is one down counter in the system available for this purpose. So the kernel has to keep track of all the processes it has to send a signal to, with one down counter. How does it do it?

[Does it maintain a linked list of sort, with each node signifying the process?]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm no Linux kernel developer, but given the [man-page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/alarm) for `alarm()`, you can already expect how it is implemented.

First, it is clear that the alarm value is per process. Since the kernel already keeps per-process data structures ([`task_struct`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/ds/ds.html)), it just stores the desired alarm time in there. Then Linux just uses its internal timer system to register a callback at the specified time. Said callback then delivers the SIGALRM to your process.

No need for kernel-global state or linked explicit linked lists for the alarms. The kernel simply keeps a process list and stores the alarm timeout as part of the per process data.

If you want to dig deeper, the calling tree looks something like this:

- [sys_alarm()](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+%2a/kernel/timer.c#L1394)
- [alarm_setitimer()](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.13.5/kernel/itimer.c#L253)
- [do_setitimer()](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.13.5/kernel/itimer.c#L190): This stores a kernel timer under as `task_struct->signal->real_timer`; it then passes calls
- [hrtimer_start()](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.13.5/include/linux/hrtimer.h#L360), which is part of Linux' internal high resolution timer API.

Digging even further, the Linux high-res kernel timer system does a whole number of things, e.g. distinguishing between real time (which may go backwards if someone changes the time/date on the computer) and monotonic time. Take a look at [this LWN article](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.13.5/kernel/hrtimer.c#L881) for an overview.

For the purposes of this question, it internally keeps a list of timers ordered by expiry time (soon to expire timers first, later expiring timers last). For performance reasons, this is not implemented as a doubly-linked list but as a [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree). After the any callback has been handled, hrtimers looks at its list, picks the first entry (the soonest to expire timer) and then tells the underlaying hardware timer to interrupt in time to service the next event. When that happens, hrtimers invokes the relevant callback, and the process repeats.

So there are timer lists (implemented as trees), but no explicit down counter, that part is handled via hardware timers. A leading reference for that part of the source code is [enqueue_hrtimer()](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.13.5/kernel/hrtimer.c#L873).

Comment: but how is the callback triggered at the required time? There is a down counter for that. But how are so many alarms from so many processes managed by the kernel? This is my doubt!

Comment: See file `kernel/time/alarmtimer.c` in kernel source tree (maybe `include/linux/timerqueue.h` as well). Usually nothing beats reading the source.

Comment: It would help if I could read all the kernel source with no problem! If I do start reading it now, then I'll probably end up more confused.

Comment: I updated my answer to dig a bit into how hrtimers themselves work. Hope this answers your questions.