# who send SIGALRM signal?

Tags: c, linux, timer, operating-system

I don't understand how timer functions (such as setTimeOut in NodeJS) work. After some search, It seems to be related to alarm() function for Linux in the end (CreateWaitableTimer for windows maybe). the description of this function is:

> arranges for a SIGALRM signal to be delivered to the calling process in seconds seconds

My question are:

1. And this SIGALRM seem to be process level not thread level. Is it
   really related to timer functions?
2. The SIGALRM is to be delivered by whom?

My guess is there could be two ways. One is when CPU schedule process it check the time, if OK then send SIGALRM. Two is there's some kind of hardware that knows the time and send the SIGALRM.

All the above description could be incorrect as I know very few of low level programming or OS/hardware knowledge. So Please instruct me the answer and any other thing I get wrong.

Comment: While node.js is asynchronous, it is still single-threaded. If you're interested about how signals and other lower-level functions work then you need to start learning C and read about POSIX systems programming (or its equivalents on Windows).

Comment: The CPU does not do any of that directly. It provides service to the kernel (e.g. timer interrupts) which the kernel uses to implement OS type services (e.g. scheduling of user processes and user level timers).

Comment: Does it really matter? It could be wheels and gears that trigger the signal. POSIX and other standards don't specify that. The important thing is the process receives the signal "alarm clock rings".

Comment: @tofro Thanks for your reply. My question is what are for example the wheels or gears. Some software program or some hardware? It doesn't really matter how I program applications using timers, but just curious.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks for your reply. So the kernel implement the timer right? Then how does kernel know if time is up? I think either by busy waiting (which may waste CPU) or interrupt by some other hardware. Am I correct?

Comment: Found this [how linux's alarm() is handled by kernel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22437779/3762627). Does this help?

Comment: @InsaneRabbit Definetely not by busy wait. Hardware interrupt is the way.

Comment: @Gil-Mor very helpful. Thanks. As that answer mentioned, "kernel tells the underlaying hardware timer to interrupt in time to service the next event." Do you know which hardware for example do the interrupt? And how does it interrupt? Send a SIGALRM or do something else?

Comment: @InsaneRabbit I think you'll find an answer (or at least more directions to dig in) [here](http://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupts).