# how to trace where the SIGALRM signal comes from?

Tags: java, signals, strace

We have one java application which is based on karaf container, and this application exit every 5-6 days, we investigated and found,

1. no JVM OOM is occured, and gc logs shows memory is OK and can be collected normally.
2. no linux system OOM kill is occured, no log in 'dmesg' and /var/log/messages.
3. JVM didn't corrupt, no hs_err or core file is generated

and we tried to strace the application like below,

```
nohup strace -tt -e trace=signal -p 7428 -o /tmp/app.strace >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

and we got below info from the strace log file,

```
[root@admin ~]# cat /tmp/app.strace 
14:33:53.561413 +++ killed by SIGALRM +++
```

the '-f' option of strace is not used since it will cause the application response very slow and will cause the service unusable.

Question is, how could we know which program send the SIGALRM to this application? Thanks!

Comment: As far as I undertstand [What’s the difference between SIGALRM and SIGVTALRM?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/588104/266568) it is a kind of timer ...

Comment: ... and it is sent by Kernel, see [How Linux's `alarm()` is handled by Kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22437779/6771046).

Comment: I guess next step could be to try and trace calls to the alarm(2) syscall to see who is calling it.

Comment: if the syscall is not from the process itself but other processes, how should we trace? Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't use strace. I'd use something like stackcount (https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/stackcount_example.txt), to see calls to alarm and who called it.